# “draft” class/package option with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: koma-script, draft, scrlayer-scrpage

According to the KOMA-Script documentation, setting the `draft` option has the following effect with `scrlayer`:

> The command `\layercontentsmeasure` prints a ruler at each layer edge,
>   of which the top and left one is labelled with centimeters, the right
>   and bottom one with inches. This command is used internally, if option
>   `draft` is enabled. The rulers will be drawn behind the content of
>   each layer. It can also be used as exclusive content of a layer.

That sounds nice, but trying a trivial example document:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

gives me this:

[image: Output for minimal example with <code>draft</code> and <code>scrlayer-scrpage</code>]

That’s no good, it’s all jumbled together and I can’t tell the rulers apart!
Is there a way to make this actually useful by making it readable (e. g. reduce the size of the marks and the font size)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any pagestyle defined by `scrlayer-scrpage` consists of 10 layers. You can use `\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{#1\newline}` to get a list of these layers in your document.

On each page with a `scrlayer-scrpage` pagestyle 6 of these layers are used: one for the line above the header, one (depending on oneside or twoside document and even or odd page) for the header, one for the line below the header and the same for the footer.

If you use option `draft` for `scrlayer-scrpage` rulers for all layers on a page are shown at the same time. So you get three rulers in the header overlapping eachother and you can not read anything.

So I would clone the layers manually and add the clones to the pagestyle. Now I can color the rulers and I can decide which one I want to see.

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \newcommand*\showlayer[2][black]{%
        \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{#2}{%
            \DeclareNewLayer[clone=#2,contents=\textcolor{#1}{\layercontentsmeasure}]{#2.size}%
            \AddLayersToPageStyleAfterLayer{scrheadings}{#2.size}{#2}%
        }{}%
    }
    \showlayer[lightgray]{scrheadings.head.oneside}
    \showlayer[red!30]{scrheadings.head.below.line}
    %\showlayer[green!30]{scrheadings.head.above.line}
    \showlayer[lightgray]{scrheadings.foot.oneside}
    %\showlayer[red!30]{scrheadings.foot.above.line}
    %\showlayer[green!30]{scrheadings.foot.below line}

    \chead{Test header}
    \cfoot{Test footer}

    \begin{document}

    \minisec{List the layers for pagestyle scrheadings}

    \begin{flushleft}
    \ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{#1\newline}
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note the position of layer `scrheadings.head.below.line`: It is the position of the layer! The definition of `contents` is not restricted to this area. With option `headsepline` and showing only the layer `scrheadings.head.below.line` by `\showlayer[red]{scrheadings.head.below.line}` I get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I guess I was hoping the `draft` option would do something actually useful (“work by default”) in `scrlayer-scrpage`, but I guess not.

Comment: It could be useful if you design new layers for a new layer page style.